# transaction not rolling back - scope issue?

Tags: sql, vb.net, transactions, scope, rollback

I'm having a hard time understanding why I can't get this transaction to roll back. I have a DataAccess object that handles the connection/transaction. I have a MailingData business object, and a MailingDataAccess object which takes the DataAccess object byRef from the MailingData object and executes a stored procedure. I immediately rollback the update, but it doesn't roll back. I'm guessing this is a scope issue. Help? I was doing byval with dataaccess, but that wasn't working so I changed to byref.

vb.net console app - 
code:

```
     Dim da As DataAccess = New DataAccess("mydb")

     Try
        ' business object
        Dim mailingData as New MailingData()

        ' start a transaction
        da.StartTransaction()

        ' do stuff, set properties...

        ' pass the data access object byref to a method that calls a stored proc
        mailingData.UpdateCategorize(da)


        ' testing, this doesn't roll back the update from the above stored proc            
        da.RollBackTransaction()

        'da.CommitTransaction()
    Catch ex As Exception
        da.RollBackTransaction()

    End Try
```

My data access object:

```
    Private _database As Database
    Private _transaction As Data.IDbTransaction
    Private _connection As Data.IDbConnection


    Public ReadOnly Property Database() As Database
        Get
            Return _database
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Connection() As IDbConnection
        Get
            Return _connection
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Transaction() As Data.IDbTransaction
        Get
            Return _transaction
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _database = GetDatabase()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal database As String)
        _database = GetDatabase(database)
    End Sub


    Private Function GetDatabase() As Database

        Return DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()

    End Function


    Private Function GetDatabase(ByVal database As String) As Database
            Return DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(database)
    End Function

    '-- if not transaction started, start new one.
    Public Sub StartTransaction()
        If _transaction Is Nothing Then
            _connection = _database.CreateConnection()

            _connection.Open()
            _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub CommitTransaction()
        _transaction.Commit()
        If Not IsNothing(Connection) Then
            Connection.Close()
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub RollBackTransaction()

        _transaction.Rollback()

        If Not IsNothing(Connection) Then
            Connection.Close()
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

mailingData.UpdateCategorize() is defined within the mailingData business object as:

```
Public Function UpdateCategorize(ByRef da As DataAccess) As Integer
    Dim mailingDA As New MailingDataAccess

    Return mailingDA.UpdateCategorize(da, Me)
End Function
```

MailingDataAccess.UpdateCategorize is defined as:

```
Public Function UpdateCategorize(ByRef da As DataAccess, ByVal clsMailing As MailingData) As Integer
        Dim db As Database = da.Database

        Dim DbCommand As DbCommand
        Dim dbStatus As Integer = 0

        DbCommand = da.Database.GetStoredProcCommand("proc_UpdateCategorize")
        With db
            .AddInParameter(DbCommand, "@pMailingID", Data.DbType.Int32, clsMailing.MailingID)

        dbStatus = db.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand)

        Return dbStatus
    End Function
```

Comment: @Steve, since he's using `ExecuteNonQuery`, I think it's mssql

Comment: sorry, SQL Server 2008.. entity framewoork

Comment: bah! enterprise library, not entity framework... i'm all over the place today

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Does your stored proc have any transaction control in it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this line:

```
 dbStatus = db.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand)
```

should be:

```
 dbStatus = db.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand, da.Transaction)
```